# How to drop element /drag&drop kanban sort of thing/ to it's initial position

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm a newbie to programming and I encountered a problem, as follows: 
I have an element, 'Item 1', which won't go back to the first ('motherland') ul list.

From debbuging, I know that when I try to drag and drop it from "In progress", "Done", or back to "To do" it executes only the drag function - without drop as it should - Why?

From html file:

```
<div id="board">
    <div>
        <h1>To do</h1>
        <h1>In progress</h1>
        <h1>Done</h1>
    </div>

    <ul id="todo">
        <li id="item1" draggable="true"ondragstart="drag(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">Task 1</li>
        <li id="item2">Task 2</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="inprogress" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>


    <ul id="done" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>


</div>
```

From js file :

```
function allowDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(allowDrop);
}



function drag(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
    console.log(drag);
}



function drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));


    console.log(drop);
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ondrop="drop(event)" in the ul tag instead of the li tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I supposed that sth need to be wrong with nodes ... parents, children etc :). Your's solution worked after I moved ondragover=allowDrop(event) together with ondrop="drop(event) from <li> to <ul> tag :)